# Im working with javaFX, when i try .equal object it is not working

Tags: java, object, javafx, methods

I am working with java FX and trying to do a login page. For some reason .equal is not working. I'm doing the sout for testing purposes as I later will connect it with a database.

```
public class loginPage {
    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField loginPassword;

    @FXML
    private TextField loginUsername;

    @FXML
    private Button loginBtn;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        String loginPsw = loginPassword.getText();
        String loginName = loginUsername.getText().trim();

        loginBtn.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            if (!loginName.equals("") || !loginPsw.equals("")){
                loginFunction(loginName , loginPsw);
            }else {
                System.out.println("prova");
            }
        });

    }

    private void loginFunction(String loginUsername, String loginPassword) {
        System.out.println("sukses");
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *"not working"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `Objects` to a method that is looking for `Strings`. Get the info from the `TextField` when the `loginBtn` is pressed. You are currently trying to get the info from the `TextFields` when the program is initialized.

```
@FXML
void initialize() {
    //String loginPsw = loginPassword.getText();
    //String loginName = loginUsername.getText().trim();

    loginBtn.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
        if (loginUsername.getText().length() > 0 && loginUsername.getText().length > 0){
            loginFunction(loginUsername.getText().trim(), loginPassword.getText());
        }else {
            System.out.println("prova");
        }
    });

}

private void loginFunction(String loginUsername, String loginPassword) {
    System.out.println("sukses");
}
```

for

```
loginUsername.getText().length() > 0 && loginUsername.getText().length > 0
```

you could also use

```
!textfield.getText().isBlank() && !passwordField.getText().isBlank()
```

or

```
!textfield.getText().isEmpty()&& !passwordField.getText().isEmpty()
```

depending on what case works for you.